# Does ls -l print the file size in blocks or bytes?

Tags: shell, unix, ls

I created a new file on a unix server.

Now, `ls -l` prints the following:

```sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mccorm14 student 49508 Oct 26 11:29 4th
```

Does `ls -l` print the file size (`49508`) in blocks or bytes? If it is blocks, how do I convert it to bytes?

Comment: read manual, ls -s  print alloated size of each file in blocks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ls -l` lists file sizes in bytes. No conversion necessary. For readability you can use `-h` to print human readable sizes like `49K`.

You may be thinking of `du`, which uses block size by default. For `du` try `-h` to print human readable sizes or `-k` to set the block size to 1KiB.